# jquery attr('checked', false) bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery **version 1.8** I am able to check and uncheck a checkbox by `$el.attr('checked', logic_value)`:

http://jsbin.com/oyIQuJo/1/edit

Using jquery **version 1.10.1** (or **2.0.2**) it changes just once to checked then to unchecked and I can't set it checked again:

http://jsbin.com/oyIQuJo/2/edit

http://jsbin.com/oyIQuJo/3/edit

Is it a known behaviour/bug? What is the best way to do that so I can switch it checked/unchecked multiple times?

I could do `$el[0].checked = logic_value` (http://jsbin.com/oyIQuJo/4/edit), but I don't really like this solution, because then I should loop over all the elements of the selector if it has more than one element.

Comment: `"As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method."` http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 5):

You have to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`. Because `.prop()` is actually made for setting properties like `checked`,`selected` etc..

The proper way would be,

```
$el.prop('checked', logic_value)
```

Please read [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get a grip over `.prop()`